# Apps Script Google Sheets , ¿como insertar el valor de un rango de celdas combinadas en el rango una sola celda?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo

Estoy trabajando con una plantilla de google sheets que tiene un rango de celdas en las columna *E:F* que están combinadas,estoy haciendo en un script que inserta ciertos datos de la plantilla en una nueva hoja generada   , quisiera saber si hay una forma  de que los datos que están en esas celdas combinadas, sea posible insertarlo en solo el rango de celdas de una sola columna . Por ejemplo el rango de *E1:F10* en solo el rango de *F1:F10* de la nueva hoja.

```
 var rangoHoja1 = hoja1.getRange(E1:F10).getValues();
var rangoHojaDestino = hoja2.getRange(F1:F10);
rangoHojaDesitno.setValues(rangoHoja1);
```

Usando esta linea de código falla debido a que no permite insertar el rango de dos columnas en una sola aunque estas ultimas estén combinadas horizontalmente, si bien lo mas sencillo seria separar las celdas que están combinadas , me gustaría saber si hay alguna otra alternativa.

Answer (score 1):

En lugar de utilizar la función `getValues()` directamente en el rango que contiene las celdas combinadas, puedes utilizar la función `getDisplayValues()`, que devuelve los valores que se muestran en las celdas, incluyendo las celdas combinadas.

Luego, para extraer solo los valores de una de las columnas, puedes utilizar la función `map()` de JavaScript para crear un nuevo array que contenga solo los valores de la columna que necesitas. Por ejemplo:

```
var rangoHoja1 = hoja1.getRange("E1:F10").getDisplayValues();
var columnaF = rangoHoja1.map(function(fila) {
  return fila[1]; // retorna el valor de la columna F (índice 1) de cada fila
});
```

En este ejemplo, la variable `columnaF` será un array que contiene los valores de la columna F de las celdas combinadas del rango E1:F10.

Luego, puedes insertar estos valores en el rango de celdas de la nueva hoja utilizando la función `setValues()` de la misma manera que lo estabas haciendo antes:

```
var rangoHojaDestino = hoja2.getRange("F1:F10");
rangoHojaDestino.setValues(columnaF);
```

Con esto, los valores de la columna F de las celdas combinadas del rango E1:F10 se insertarán correctamente en el rango de celdas F1:F10 de la nueva hoja.